# Can "Watching now" be disabled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, video-streaming, facebook-videos

I was watching a snooker game live stream on Facebook and noticed a FB friend being displayed as (also) *Watching now*:

[image]

They also mention it in the comments next to the video (which scrolls out of view of course):

[image]

This is innoccent, but suppose I'm watching something that I feel uncomfortable with letting others know. **Can this be disabled**, either through a FB setting or a tool?

I did not find anything in the FB privacy settings or through [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+disable+%22watching+now%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b).

Comment: Turning off "active status" might do it, but I haven't tested it. https://www.facebook.com/help/215888465102253

Answer (score 0):

According to [Lucia Summa's post on SocialBuddy](https://socialbuddy.com/can-i-see-who-views-my-facebook-live/), you are able to watch a Facebook Live video anonymously as long as you don’t do any of the following:

- click on the live video
- like the video
- comment on the video
- share the video